# Javascript If Statement, not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a JavaScript function that I want to use to get the current URL and if there is any value after the = then it should placed in a textbox that has an ID of name. However at the moment, when I open the page, the full URL is displayed in the text box, so I want to have some kind of condition where it only displays if there is a value after the only =

```
function DisplayProdCod(value) {
    var URLstring = window.location.href;
    if (URLstring.indexOf('=')) {
        var ProductCode = URLstring.split("=").pop();
        document.getElementById('Name').value = ProductCode;
        document.getElementById('Name').style.backgroundColor = #C8C8FF;
    }
}
```

A typical URL could be

http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMFRAME.html

or

http://brmappsvr:7018/Enquiries/CMFRAME.html?ProductCode=1BLK970/07

Comment: `URLstring.indexOf('=')` returns -1 if character doesn't exist and your condition will be `true` unless your URL starts with `=`

Comment: if (URLstring.indexOf('=') > -1) {}

Comment: Like other people pointed out, your if condition is not correct. Apart from that, your code should work.

Comment: i have posted an answer check it and let me know if you have still problems

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to check if returns `-1`, like so:

```
function DisplayProdCod(value) {
    var URLstring = window.location.href;
    if (URLstring.indexOf('=') != -1) {
        var ProductCode = URLstring.split("=").pop();
        document.getElementById('Name').value = ProductCode;
        document.getElementById('Name').style.backgroundColor = #C8C8FF;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does that fix his problem? He says the entire URL is pasted to the textbox, and that wouldn't be the case if the problem lies in the if-condition.

Answer (score 0):

The `indexOf` function returns `-1` when the character you are searching for does not occur in the string. And as every number (except 0) is truthy the condition in your if-condition is met everytime. So you should better check if the index is greater than `-1`, i.e.

```
if (URLstring.indexOf('=') > -1) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That most likely does not solve his problem though, because if the problem was the if-condition, the entire URL would not be pasted to the textbox.

Comment: The reason that there is the whole URL displayed in the textfield is that, when there is no `=` in the URL then `URLstring.split("=").pop()` returns just the whole URL. So this will solve his problem, as this can not happen any more and when there is an `=` in the URL the text after the `=` will be display. Have you even tested OPs code?  Or are you just assuming what his problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Just do URLstring.split('=') anyway, then check the length of the result. If it's 2, work with result[1], otherwise something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
**Example**

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="Name"/>
<input type="button" onclick="DisplayProdCod();" value="click"/>
```

**JS**

```
function DisplayProdCod() {
    var URLstring = window.location.href;
    alert(URLstring);
    if (URLstring.indexOf("=") > -1) {
        var ProductCode = URLstring.split("=").pop();
        document.getElementById("Name").value = ProductCode;
        document.getElementById('Name').style.backgroundColor ="#C8C8FF";
    }
}
```

See the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLk5bwpy/)** in this demo i am searching a string "fiddle" you can replace it with "=" in your program

**Note**:
in your code you are missed a double quotes when you setting a background colour
it should be like below

```
document.getElementById('Name').style.backgroundColor ="#C8C8FF";
```